Facing problem in Excel VBA where the code goes into loop but skips the last row of that loop
I'm currently using VBA to check if content of column E (say row X) matches with that of content in column B (say row Y). Let's say value of X:E is 'a' then it will find if 'a' exists in any of the rows in column B. Let's say there are 4 rows that have value 'a'. Based on another condition, it will find row Y out of these 4 rows. Let's say 3rd row is my required row Y. But code is giving the output as 2nd row i.e. the row just previous to the required row. How do I solve it?
The output expected is 'a' of column E in row X matches with 'a' of column B in row Y. Below is the code:
Sub CaseOneTwoandFour()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim componentNames As New Collection
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim item As Variant
    Dim foundRow As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim cellValue As Variant
    Dim matchRow As Long
    Dim matchFound As Boolean
    Dim tempValue As Variant
    Dim initialRowColor As Long
    
    ' Set the worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Find the last row
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Loop through each cell in column A and add unique component names to the collection
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each cell In ws.Range("A5:A" & lastRow)
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            componentNames.Add cell.Value, CStr(cell.Value)
        End If
    Next cell
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    For Each item In componentNames
        ' Find the row with the specified component name in column A
        foundRow = Application.Match(item, ws.Range("A5:A" & lastRow), 0)
        If IsError(foundRow) Then Exit Sub
        
        ' Loop through rows below the found component name row
        For i = 5 To lastRow
            cellValue = ws.Cells(i, 3).Value
            
            ' Check if columns D and E or columns F and G have content
            If (Len(Trim(ws.Cells(i, 4).Value)) > 0 And Len(Trim(ws.Cells(i, 5).Value)) > 0) Or _
               (Len(Trim(ws.Cells(i, 6).Value)) > 0 And Len(Trim(ws.Cells(i, 7).Value)) > 0) Then
                
                matchFound = False
                
                ' Check if contents from either column E (5) or G (7) match any cell in column B (2)
                For j = 5 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
                    If StrComp(ws.Cells(j, 2).Value, ws.Cells(i, 5).Value, vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Or _
                       StrComp(ws.Cells(j, 2).Value, ws.Cells(i, 7).Value, vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
                        
                        If Not ws.Rows(j).Find(What:=cellValue, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
                            matchRow = j
                            matchFound = True
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End If
                Next j
                
                If matchFound Then
                    ' Ensure matchRow is set before trying to access it
                    If matchRow > 0 Then
                        If Len(Trim(ws.Cells(matchRow, 5).Value)) > 0 Then
                            tempValue = ws.Cells(matchRow, 5).Value
                        ElseIf Len(Trim(ws.Cells(matchRow, 7).Value)) > 0 Then
                            tempValue = ws.Cells(matchRow, 7).Value
                        End If
                        
                        initialRowColor = ws.Cells(i, 8).Interior.Color
                        If StrComp(ws.Cells(i, 2).Value, tempValue, vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
                            ws.Cells(i, 8).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) ' Green color for initial row
                            ws.Cells(matchRow, 8).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) ' Green color for matched row
                        Else
                            ws.Cells(i, 8).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Red color
                            ws.Cells(i, 9).Value = "Wrong Connection"
                        End If
                    End If
                Else
                    ws.Cells(i, 8).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Red color
                    ws.Cells(i, 9).Value = "Wrong Connection"
                End If
            End If
            
            ' Highlight red if E or G has content but D or F does not respectively
            If (Len(Trim(ws.Cells(i, 5).Value)) > 0 And Len(Trim(ws.Cells(i, 4).Value)) = 0) Or _
               (Len(Trim(ws.Cells(i, 7).Value)) > 0 And Len(Trim(ws.Cells(i, 6).Value)) = 0) Then
                ws.Cells(i, 8).Interior.Color = IIf(StrComp(item, "connector", vbBinaryCompare) = 0, RGB(255, 255, 0), RGB(255, 0, 0))
                If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = "connector" Then ws.Cells(i, 8).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                ws.Cells(i, 9).Value = "One of the connections is absent for Connector"
            End If
            
            ' Highlight red if all columns D, E, F, and G are empty
            If Len(Trim(ws.Cells(i, 4).Value)) = 0 And Len(Trim(ws.Cells(i, 5).Value)) = 0 And _
               Len(Trim(ws.Cells(i, 6).Value)) = 0 And Len(Trim(ws.Cells(i, 7).Value)) = 0 Then
                ws.Cells(i, 8).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) ' Red color
                ws.Cells(i, 9).Value = "There is interaction with non-terminal component (No Producer or Consumer)"
            End If
            
            ' If all columns D, E, F, and G have content, give red color
            If Len(Trim(ws.Cells(i, 4).Value)) > 0 And Len(Trim(ws.Cells(i, 5).Value)) > 0 And _
               Len(Trim(ws.Cells(i, 6).Value)) > 0 And Len(Trim(ws.Cells(i, 7).Value)) > 0 Then
                ws.Cells(i, 8).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Red color
            End If
            
        Next i
    Next item
End Sub


I'm not great with VBA, but I know that a common "gotcha" is zero indexing (starting at 0 vs starting at 1) or a condition that might skip the last iteration of a loop. Double check any particular areas that should be outputting your expected values and check if you're using indexes and make sure the indexes are the rows you actually think they are.

Have you tried inserting some debug.print statements and/or stepping through your code to check the values of different variables?

Comment ' Loop through rows below the found component name row doesn't match the following code. What's the purpose of foundRow  just above that?  You collected all the values from ColA, so there would there ever be a case where no match is made?
